# Command to find the git merge that undeleted a file

Tags: git, merge

I recently discovered that, when merging into my branch, someone mistakenly undeleted a file I deleted earlier.

When I do a git log on the path to the deleted file, the delete and the merge that undeleted the file don't appear.

If I do:

> git log deleted_sha..HEAD path_to_file

I can see there was one change (the source of the conflict that caused my delete to get clobbered). From here, it's easy to walk through the history until the bad merge.

What I'd *like* is a command to tell me in exactly what commit (i.e., the bad merge) the undelete happened.

Comment: Have you tried `git log --full-history` ?

Comment: You could also try `git blame` and, at the risk of sucking a little more time, `git bisect`.

Comment: --full-history doesn't help, it shows the commit where the file was deleted, and the commit that changed the file, but not the fateful merge which undeleted the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you just the merge commits that affected the file:

```
 git log deleted_sha.. --merges -- path/to/file
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. It just returns no output. For some reason git doesn't think the merge changed the file when it undeleted it.